# Computer boots up automatically when given power and screen shows no display?

Tags: boot, memory, ssd, motherboard, power-supply

I have a strange problem with my computer that I am building. I had to replace the original mobo (Asrock fatal1ty H97) due to compatibility issues (the system did boot up correctly with this mobo) , I have replaced it with an ASUS server motherboard P9D-E/4L. The rest of my system includes 16gb of Kingston ram, an Intel Xeon E3-1271 v3, 128gb samsung SSD, 2TB WB black HDD and a 420w thermal master PSU.

What is happening is, once I connect the power cord to the computer and hit the switch at the back, the computer turns on automatically, all LED's come on and the fans are spinning at normal speeds, however the there is no display on my monitor it indicates there is no signal, the monitor is plugged into the VGA port on the mobo and the only way to turn off the computer is to hold down the power button at the front of the computer or hit the power switch at the back.

I have triple checked all cords and connections in in the computer they are all correct. I had a feeling there was a stand off in the case that was directly touching the bottom of the mobo, I took out the mobo and did infact find an extra stand off underneath (the old motherboard had them in different places), I checked that all stands off were correct and screwed them in accordingly. Fixing this did not fix my problem. I shuffled the ram from slots 1-3 to 2-4, this did not work either.

I am a little lost at the moment as to what to do or what there else is to do.

Any suggestions as to what could be the problem and how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: I've had a machine which did very similar to what you describe in regards to the power just turning on. Some times I would hit the power button and the PC would do nothing for 2 seconds, and then turn on. The PSU blew, thankfully tripping the RCD and as such, no damage was done but I'd be cautious here - test with a different PSU if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "automatic startup" issue may be a setting in your BIOS to automatically start the machine when AC power is restored - important for servers/machines that need to be on all the time.

Regarding your "no display" problem: The Intel Xeon E3-1271 V3 does not have integrated graphics so you must install a graphics adapter into the machine.

Source: http://ark.intel.com/m/products/80908/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1271-v3-8M-Cache-3_60-GHz#@product/specifications

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! I feel like an absolute dummy now haha. I put in a dedicated GPU and it all works fine now, I also changed the BIOS setting so it doesn't wake on power automatically. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to have been able to help :) If the answer has resolved the entire question for you could you mark it as answered? Thank you